# Adjust mixing valve

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

Fairly new to  DIY plumbing.

I have moved into a new flat that has quite an old looking shower fitting. The mains  water is very hot but even the hottest setting on the shower comes out lukewarm at best. I thought there might be a small hole to adjust a mixing valve but can't see one.

I tried undoing the screws but the escutcheon  appears to be fixed to the wall and    I don't want to force it unless I know it should be removed .

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Page 12, I believe: https://assets.hansgrohe.com/mam/celum/celum_assets/16__hrgh0954_pdf.pdf?3

Comment: Unfortunately mixing valves that have temp controls wear out.  There is a cartridge in them that can be replaced to restore normal function.   That might be your problem.   But try Ecnerwal's fix first, he may be right.

Answer (score 1):

In order  to remove the escutcheon, (the big round plate with the screws in it) It may be caulked to the wall.  You first remove the handle and unscrew the round cover that is over the valve body,   this will give you access to the adjustments for limits stops that control the temperature mixing. Or the ability to remove the cartridge and replace it.

For removing the handle,there will be a set screw on the handle some were that you will have to loosen so you can pull the handle off, I am betting it is on the  under side (*bottom*) of the handle but i have seen them under the little blue and red symbol. You then need to follow the manufacturers instruction to set the temp limits.

It usually involves pulling out  (*slightly*)  a round plastic disc  that is keyed in to another round plastic part, then turning it one or several key slots  and sliding it back in. This changes how far the handle can be turned to the hot  position.